# Populate textbox 1 based on value from another (textbox 2) only if the Textbox1 is empty using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hi am a newbie to AngularJS.
I've two textboxes on the page say TextBox1 and TextBox2

The second textbox needs to be populated from TextBox1 when someone enter some values in it (1). But if TextBox 2 having a different value than TextBox1, the value of TB2 should keep there as it is.
That means TB2 value only get populated from TB1 when both the textboxes having same contents.

How can we accomplish using AngularJS.

I've this now

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<input type='text' ng-model='username' id="textbox1" />
  <input type='text' value='{{username}}' id="textbox2" />
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [the ng-change argument on input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), it accepts an [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) that you could use for the logic you describe